# Is there a way to specialize a general method of an inherited object

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two specialized objects:

```
class Food {};
class Fruit : public Food {};
class Vegetable : public Food {};
```

Then I have a parent class which will be inherited:

```
class Parent
{
    virtual void say(Food* obj) { std::cout << "The object is food" << std::endl; }
};
```

And an inherited class from the parent.

```
class Child : public Parent
{
    virtual void say(Fruit* obj) { std::cout << "The object is a fruit" << std::endl; }
    virtual void say(Vegetable* obj) { std::cout << "The object is a vegetable" << std::endl; }
};
```

I do:

```
std::vector<Food*> basket;
Fruit fruit = Fruit();
Vegetable vegetable = Vegetable();
basket.push_back(&fruit);
basket.push_back(&vegetable);

Child child = Child();

for (Food* food : basket)
{
    child.say(food);
}
```

I would like it to print "The object is a fruit" and then "The object is a vegetable", but it doesn't work :
I get the error message : no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Food*' to 'Fruit*'.

Is there a way to do it, without using typeid if possible because I heard it causes overhead. Here is a the code in an online editor: [cpp.sh/27ekc](http://cpp.sh/27ekc)

Comment: The different foods should be printing themselves polymorphically.  Then you just call that function in your `say` function.

Comment: In the real world, the child knows what she is eating. In the OOP, the food knows its own name.

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't call an overloaded method expecting polymorphism to figure out which method to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the appropriate solution to this is the following:

```
class Food 
{
public:
    virtual ~Food() = default;
    virtual void say() const;
};
class Fruit : public Food 
{
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "The object is a fruit" << std::endl; }
};
class Vegetable : public Food 
{
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "The object is a vegetable" << std::endl; }
};

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void say(const Food& obj) const { obj.say(); }
};

class Child : public Parent {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Food*> basket;
    Fruit fruit = Fruit();
    Vegetable vegetable = Vegetable();
    basket.push_back(&fruit);
    basket.push_back(&vegetable);

    Child child = Child();

    for (const Food* food : basket)
    {
        child.say(*food);
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
as per your comment, it is based on what you mean by health.
I interpret it as something along these lines:

```
class Food 
{
public:
    virtual ~Food() = default;
    virtual void say() const;
    virtual int health() const;
};
class Fruit : public Food 
{
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "The object is a fruit" << std::endl; }
    int health() const override { return 5; }
};
class Vegetable : public Food 
{
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "The object is a vegetable" << std::endl; }
    int health() const override { return 10; }
};

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void say(const Food& obj) const { obj.say(); }
};

class Child : public Parent 
{
    int health;

public:
    void eat(const Food& obj) { health += obj.health(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Food*> basket;
    Fruit fruit = Fruit();
    Vegetable vegetable = Vegetable();
    basket.push_back(&fruit);
    basket.push_back(&vegetable);

    Child child = Child();

    for (const Food* food : basket)
    {
        child.say(*food);
        child.eat(*food);
    }
}
```

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But what if say would for example add health to child?

Comment: @Talesseed: You may also look at [visitor-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/4579/visitor-pattern/15127/visitor-pattern-example-in-c#t=201612232223221431311) as alternative to add method in `Food`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, although wouldn't use this pattern here as it will complexify a class that needs to be very simple.

Comment: @Talesseed: It is a trade of. You have to consider if new method would be added, or if new class in hierarchy will be added. What you consider to be part of your base class. From your example, you don't even need hierarchy, and simple members to store health and identity seems enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I need hierarchy to store the "Food" in a single container, no? Otherwise, I will definitely consider that as an option (I didn't knew about it before too, thanks).